# WCF REST Downloading pdf with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, pdf

I'm trying to download a pdf file from a WCF REST service, using jquery ajax call but I think there's an encoding issue.

Here's the service interface method definition

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        Method="POST", 
        UriTemplate = "DownloadFile")]
    Stream DownloadFile(RequestDownloadFile fileDownload);
```

and then the implementation

```
 public Stream DownloadFile(RequestDownloadFile fileDownload)
 {
       DBCepPortaleEntities cepPortale = CEP.DAL.DbConnections.GetConnessionePortale(ConnString); //connection with entity framework to SQLServer DB

        var cerco = from cc in cepPortale.WEB_DOCUMENTI
                    where cc.IdDocumento == fileDownload.ID
                    select cc; //retrieving a Pdf VARBINARY Field
        if (cerco.Count() > 0)
        {



            WEB_DOCUMENTI doc = cerco.First();


            String nomeFile = @"test.pdf";
            String tmp = Encoding.Default.GetString(doc.DocPDF);
            File.WriteAllText(nomeFile, tmp, Encoding.Default);//test: pdf file is written correctly and I can read it
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=circolare" + fileDownload.ID + ".pdf");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "none");

            FileStream f = new FileStream(nomeFile, FileMode.Open);
            int length = (int)f.Length;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int sum = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = f.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
            {
                sum += count;
            }
            f.Close();
            return new MemoryStream(buffer); 
       }
        else
            return null;
 }
```

This method write correctly the pdf file called "test.pdf".

Now I'm trying to consume it with a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://testwcfcircolari.bresciapaghe.it/Service.svc/DownloadFile",
                    data: '{"Token":"abc", "ID":"20"}',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                        console.log(response);
                        //self.settings.onSuccessStart(response, status, xhr, self);

                        // Check if a filename is existing on the response headers.
                        var filename = "";
                        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
                        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf("attachment") !== -1) {
                            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=(([""]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                            if (matches != null && matches[1])
                                filename = matches[1].replace(/[""]/g, "");
                        }

                        filename = "prova.pdf";


                        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" });

                        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== "undefined") {
                            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed.
                            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                        } else {
                            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            alert(filename);
                            if (filename) {
                                // Use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename.
                                var a = document.createElement("a");
                                // Safari doesn"t support this yet.
                                if (typeof a.download === "undefined") {
                                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                                } else {
                                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                                    a.download = filename;
                                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                                    a.click();
                                }
                            } else {
                                window.location = downloadUrl;
                            }
                            //console.log(downloadUrl);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
                            }, 100); // Cleanup
                        }
                        // Final custom event.
                        //self.settings.onSuccessFinish(response, status, xhr, self, filename);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error occurred while opening fax template' + XMLHttpRequest + " " +
                              +textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

The result is a pdf file that have the same page of the original, but the content is all blank.
Watching with a text editor content of the downloaded pdf, it's different from the starter file.

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
String[] filename=filepath.Split('\\');            
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
if(File.Exists(filepath)
{
    String header = "attachment; filename=" + filename[filename.Length - 1];
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = header;
    return File.OpenRead(filepath);
}
```

JS

```
function downloadfile(filepath)
 {    
 var url="https://myfile.ololo?v="+filepath;
 window.open(url,"windowname","width:400,height:300");
 }
```

binding

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWcfRestService.WebHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483637"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483637"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483637"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483637"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483637"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483637"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In this way i will use GET method to retrieve file, but I need to pass token to make sure that client got permission to access to determined file: passing token on GET in not secure. Is there a way to do it?